# How to do pipeing in os.popen() ? - python

Tags: python, operating-system, pipe, popen

I've looked for days and I can't find a good explanation on how to do this. I'm trying to do the following in python:

Get time from the system and send it to a variable like:

```
time = os.popen("date +%T").read()
```

Then do something like:

```
os.system("echo time is " + time + " | festival --tts ")
```

When I do this it throws up an error about the "|". I've tired looking at subprocess.call, however I don't how I could use it to pipe the echo command to another command.

help?

Comment: Note that you don't have to use `date +%T`, see my answer below for a more pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

The main issue is that the pipe character is a shell feature and [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) doesn't use the Shell, but executes a raw command.

For example, you could use:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("echo time is " + time + " | festival --tts ", shell=True)
```

You need to use `shell=True` in this case as keyword argument so it doesn't complain about the pipe.

Note: Generally, you should take care that nothing from untrusted sources is executed as system/shell command. In your specific case this seems to be no real issue because you're assembling the command from a `date` output only, but in general it could lead to major security issues.

Also note that there's no reason to execute `date +%T`, use this instead:

```
import time
mytime = time.strftime("%H:%m:%S")
```

(note that the variable is named mytime in this case, to avoid shadowing the time module)